# Unknown column due to second-level subquery nesting

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I want to retrieve a user's *rank* based on how many points the given user has compared to other users (simply counting users with more points than the given user).

However, with all the queries I have tried, I always end up with `Column not found: users.id`. From what I can read there is a limit from referencing correlated parent columns more than one level up.

Can I refactor my query, or do I really need to use `SET @rownum := 0` style of queries?

```
SELECT 
    `users`.*, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
        FROM (
            SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS `all_points` 
            FROM `points` 
            WHERE `type` = ? 
            GROUP BY `user_id` 
            HAVING `all_points` > (
                SELECT SUM(`amount`) 
                FROM `points` 
                WHERE `type` = ? and `user_id` = `users`.`id`
            )
        ) `points_sub`
    ) as `rank` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `users`.`id` = ? 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: MySQL does not support correlation clauses more than one level deep.  Switch to MySQL 8+ and use window functions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your suggestion. I was hoping not having to upgrade the MySQL version for the whole application.

Comment: . . That was a bit tongue-in-cheek.  Your question suggests that you understand another method using variables, so go for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your sub clause one level up, Remove `having` filter and use `where` filter

```
SELECT 
    `users`.*, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
        FROM (
            SELECT user_id,SUM(`amount`) AS `all_points` 
            FROM `points` 
            WHERE `type` = ? 
            GROUP BY `user_id` 
        ) `points_sub`
        WHERE `all_points` > 
                SELECT SUM(`amount`) 
                FROM `points` 
                WHERE `type` = ? and `user_id` = `users`.`id`

    ) as `rank` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `users`.`id` = ?
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had not thought I could put that WHERE clause outside `points_sub`.

Comment: I had to put parenthesis around the `WHERE all_points > SELECT SUM(amount)` part, but then it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the below query should work for you. You can pass the user_id of user whose rank you want to compute in both the arguments.

```
SELECT 
`users`.*, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
    FROM (
        SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS `all_points` 
        FROM `points` 
        WHERE `type` = ? 
        GROUP BY `user_id` 
        HAVING `all_points` > (
            SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`amount`),0) 
            FROM `points` 
            WHERE `type` = ? and `user_id` = ?
        )
    ) `points_sub`
) as `rank` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `users`.`id` = ? 
LIMIT 1
```